# okta integration with spring mvc rest api oauth2

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2, okta, okta-api

I am trying to integrate Okta over an existing application which is built on Spring Security Rest Api Oauth2. I have integrated okta with spring boot application successfully but stuck with this application (Spring Security Rest Api Oauth2). The spring boot configuration/steps are not working with spring mvc rest api framework.
Configuration which is used in spring boot application was:

- Adding client Id and Client Secret in  properties file
- @EnableOAuth2Ssso annotation
- and a little change in the web security configuration file

Can anybody help me in configuring okta with spring mvc Rest api Oauth2 enabld application?

Answer (score 0):

Following are some good reference projects that I also used when integrating OKTA to an existing spring boot application. Hope it helps:

- [With XML configuration](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-saml2-okta)
- [With java based annotated configuration](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample)